# Separate filter results in the same view

Tags: views

How do I display the two results from two different filters in the same view?

I have this record data which has a created date field. I'd like to create a view block where display a table counting records that were created before this date and records created on of after that date.

How could I display those results from separate filters?

Comment: You would have to create another view that has greater than date and programmatically pass the filter date value from view 1 to view 2.

Comment: Is it possible to use the views_field_view module?

Comment: It depends where the filter is at, if it's a contextual filter than yes. If it's a regular filter, then you will have to do it programmatically [like this](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/2744/drupal-7-views-3-x-how-to-programmatically-render-a-view-display-passing-exposed-filter-inputs-via-code-using-view). **Note:** this is a D7 example, hopefully it's still the same for D8.